# How to send a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I want to send a request look like this:

```
POST /accounts/211242/followers HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
User-Agent: <user-agent>
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://website.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Cookie: <user-cookie>
```

But I don't know much about Javascript. I have  tried a lot but everything I got just an error. Can anyone create a code for me?
Here what I have tried:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSRF Demo</title>
</head>  
<body>
  <script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://website.com/accounts/211242/followers");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
    xmlhttp.send(null);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And after run that code, the browser sends a request:

```
POST /accounts/211242/followers HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin: null
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: <user-cookie>
```

Which don't have 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' so the server sends back `400 Bad Request`

Comment: Please share what have you tried ? Also try to give [mre] while asking questions.

Comment: Here what I have tried:  ```<html><head></head><body><script>var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://website.com/accounts/211242/followers");   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader();   xmlhttp.send(null);</script></body></html>```

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60106982/edit) button and edit the question itself providing the details.

Comment: @stud3nt Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader), you should add `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');`
after opening and before sending the request, to append the desired header.

Comment: I have tried it but my broswer just send an OPTIONS request ```OPTIONS /accounts/211242/followers...Access-Control-Request-Method: POST...Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with...``` which turned back a 404 response from server and no POST request be sent.

Comment: This would mean that the endpoint or the resource doesn't exist on the serverside. Chech if the account 211242 exists, if it has followers, and if the route exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although that's not the solution, but thank you for your contribute, I will investigate more!

Comment: Hi @taubi19, I found that the website send the POST request without an OPTIONS request before, but why it happened with me? :(

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure why it happened, but you should study [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)